# textBox is not firstResponder even though it is the only textBox I have picked

Tags: ios7, first-responder

As soon as I run the program, I select the first textBox and then select a second textBox. fNameDone runs when textBox 1 touchUpOutside.The NSLogs are there to check if the textbox is the first responder and both nslogs return false. But it is the only textBox I have picked. My ultimate goal is to have each text box I pick, the keyboard goes away when I touchUpOutside.

```
- (IBAction)fNameDone:(id)sender
{
    if([_firstName isEditing])
        NSLog(@"True");
    else
        NSLog(@"False");
    [self.view endEditing:TRUE];
    if([_firstName isEditing])
        NSLog(@"True");
    else
        NSLog(@"False");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (there is no textbox in iOS I think you mean TextField)

```
  - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)aTextField
    {
        if(aTextField.tag == 100){

          [pickerView setHidden:YES];
          return NO;
        }

        [aTextField resignFirstResponder];
        return YES;
    }
```

Don't forgot to set the delegate of textfield

**EDIT:**

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if(aTextField.tag == 100){
          firstField.inputVIew = pickerView ;
        }
}
```

Comment: I have multiple textFields. One of the textFields pulls up a datePicker. When I have selected any of the other fields that pull up a keyboard, I cant see the datePicker on that textField when I chose it. How does this function work when there are multiple textFields?

Comment: this delegate method simply resign the first responder of the textfield(keyboard or datepicker).The reason for not showing the datepicker may be you may not set the `inputView` property of textfield as pickerview

Comment: The datePicker shows up fine when I select it first. But if select another textField that pulls up a keyboard and then select the datePicker textField, the keyboard stays and I would assume covers up the datePicker.

Comment: Ok so we're one step closer. Now when I select the textField that pulls up the datePicker, the keyboard also pops up.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48923/discussion-between-lml-and-johnny-cox)